# Extracting a range of grid cells

Tags: r, raster

I have a RasterStack object, called RCP1pctCO2Median, and would like to extract the values across a range of grid cells in ocean areas. I would like to average values across the range of grid cells

RCP1pctCO2Median looks like this:

```
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 64, 128, 8192, 138  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 2.8125, 2.789327  (x, y)
extent      : -181.4062, 178.5938, -89.25846, 89.25846  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       :    layer.1,    layer.2,    layer.3,    layer.4,    layer.5,    layer.6,    layer.7,       
layer.8,    layer.9,   layer.10,   layer.11,   layer.12,   layer.13,   layer.14,   layer.15, ... 
min values  : 0.42964514, 0.43375653, 0.51749371, 0.50838983, 0.45366730, 0.53099146, 0.49757186,    
0.45697752, 0.41382199, 0.46082401, 0.45516687, 0.51857087, 0.41005131, 0.45956529, 0.47497867, ... 
max values  :   96.30350,  104.08584,   88.92751,   97.49373,   89.57201,   90.58570,   86.67651,     
88.33519,   96.94720,  101.58247,   96.07792,   93.21948,   99.59785,   94.26218,   90.62138, ...
```

I tried the following to specify the range of longitudes and latitudes using wrld_simpl:

```
data("wrld_simpl")
b <- wrld_simpl

ext <- extent(c(-120, -100, -10, 10)) #specifies a range of longitudes and latitudes
g <- (RCP1pctCO2Median, ext)
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
Error in as.integer(round(y)) : 
cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'integer'
```

Why would this error occur?

I know that wrld_simpl captures specific countries, but I am interested in isolated specific regions in oceans, as well. Unless is it possible to use wrld_simpl to capture oceanic regions?

Comment: Can you clarify what is your desired output? Perhaps by adding a reproducible example? are you sure you don't want to `crop()` your rasterstack?

Comment: @Majid Yes - ultimately, I just want to isolate the range of coordinates that I specified in the "extent" command, but I end up with that error above. Maybe "extent" is also not the best way and cropping is? Ultimately, I just want to average the values across those isolated grid cells for each layer of the raster stack. Thanks

Comment: @Majid I managed to figure it out using the crop and extent functions, and apply the averaging that I wanted to do. :) Thanks, again!